# Updating the code through executes

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, updates

I'm a beginner programmer and I'm trying to learn SQL and I've run into an issue here the question I was given is:

> Write a procedure `UpdateSuggestedPrice` that accepts an ISBN number and a new suggested price.If the ISBN does not exist, raise an error message.  Update the suggested price to the new price if there are no errors.

```
Create PROCEDURE UpdateSuggestedPrice (@ISBN char(10), @SuggestedPrice smallmoney)
AS
BEGIN
   if @ISBN is null
   Begin
     Raiserror ('Provide a valid ISBN',16,1)
   End
   else
   Begin    
     if (select COUNT(*) from Title where SuggestedPrice = @SuggestedPrice) = 0
     begin
        Select 'Description sucessfully added'

        insert into Title (SuggestedPrice)
        values (@SuggestedPrice)
     End
     Else
        Raiserror ('Description already exists',16,1)
     End
   End

   Return

-- Here I'm trying to execute the procedure, search for ISBN and 
-- then update the suggested price, can someone please tell me 
-- what I'm doing wrong.
execute UpdateSuggestedPrice @ISBN= '1021031040', @SuggestedPrice = '40'
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: You never actually do any UPDATE's?

Comment: form what the question says it doesn't seem like there should be updates in the code but instead in the test so when you test the procedure by using execute you can find a specific ISBN and update the suggested price without getting an error also fr the error i get "Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Procedure UpdateSuggestedPrice, Line 11
Invalid object name 'Title'.
"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several issues with your code.  First you are searching the data for records where `SuggestedPrice = @SuggestedPrice` - this should actually be looking for the ISBN as in `ISBN = @ISBN`.  You also are missing an `END` at the end of the stored procedure.

I would suggest re-reading the question.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE UpdateSuggestedPrice (@ISBN char(10), @SuggestedPrice smallmoney)
AS
BEGIN
   IF @ISBN is null
   BEGIN
     RAISERROR ('Provide a valid ISBN',16,1)
   END
   ELSE
   BEGIN    
     IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Title WHERE ISBN = @ISBN) = 0
     BEGIN
        RAISERROR ('ISBN does not exist.',16,1)
     END
     ELSE
     BEGIN
        SELECT 'Price sucessfully updated.';
        UPDATE Title /* Title is the table to be updated */
        SET SuggestedPrice = @SuggestedPrice /* this is the field to update */
        WHERE ISBN = @ISBN; /* this selects which record to update */
     END
   END
END 
GO
EXECUTE UpdateSuggestedPrice @ISBN= '1021031040', @SuggestedPrice = '40'
```

Comment: Thank you soo much, i've been stumped on this for a while now and could not find an answer anywere

Comment: I would suggest you look closely at the differences between your code and my answer.  Just using my code without understanding why it does what you want will not help you.

Comment: yeah i'm analyzing your code as we speak i can see my mistakes, i've been doing this code for a while so i made my silly mistakes, could you explain to me why you used  UPDATE Title and also this works for a single record in a column but if i wanted to do something like this for all the columns in a table what would i do?

Comment: Well, the question says you must update the price if the ISBN exists, but raise an error if it does not exist.  The `INSERT` you used would only ever insert a new record if any existing row had the new price.

Comment: okay so because ISBN exists you use "UPDATE Title" for the table and use SET SuggestedPrice = @SuggestedPrice so that you can update the value of it but wouldn't that also allow us to change the value of ISBN?

Comment: Yes, you could change the value of ISBN, although my code does not do that.

Comment: okay, say i wanted to change all of the values in the table instead of just the one, would i have to use multiple SET statements?